# hosting xml file causing cross domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, jsonp

I want to host my xml file, so others will have access to make ajax request (JSONP?)

I understand that cannot be achieve because there is a 'corss domain policy'.

but how can I enable it somehow for someone who wants to request it on my server?

Comment: Do they have to be able to access it through javascript only? Or can they manually download it?

Comment: they need to make jquery ajax calls to it.

Comment: What currently happens when they try to retrieve it? Did you try setting up a test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place the file in your web directory and make sure the file has read access, then it will  be accessible by just navigating to the url of the website plus the folder,

for example: www.mySiteURL.com/myxml.xml would be the link to access it after it has been uploaded to your web directory.

**EDIT**

Based on your comments you need to look into using CORS

see here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors

Quick Summary of CORS (from the website):

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a W3C spec that allows
>   cross-domain communication from the browser. By building on top of the
>   XMLHttpRequest object, CORS allows developers to work with the same
>   idioms as same-domain requests.

Comment: so if they going to jsonP request, thats the only thing they need ?

Comment: Added additional info based on your comments